# Center an image horizontally within multiple divs using css

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs that I'm adjusting using css media queries whenever the user re-sizes the page. I'm able to get everything centered but it's not consistent. All the divs should have the same css to get centered but for the `@media (max-width: 560px)` media query (the last one), I have to do this:

```
#game_box .text_holder {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#kids_devotional_box .text_holder {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#family_devotional_box .text_holder {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

My question is, why aren't all the margin-left's the same? If I set all of them to 0px or to 25px, some will be off while some will be centered. Am I doing something wrong elsewhere? Also please feel free to give me tips about my css because I am very new to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/dholl7213/kmkphavj/20/

Answer (score 0):

use the margins and paddings and all in % that may help you 
eg:

```
margin-right: 20%;
```